# XCode: Check destination platform with define

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

Do exist some standard defines, that specify destination platform, e.g. `DEST_IOS` or `DEST_OSX`? Or must I add its in project's settings?

I need this for using same library on Mac and iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Include `TargetConditionals.h`, and I use the following to make them a bit easier to use:

```
#import <TargetConditionals.h>

#if !TARGET_OS_IPHONE && !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define TARGET_OSX 1
#else
#define TARGET_IOS 1
#endif
```

(this is in a common project header file).

And then to use the macros:

```
#if TARGET_OSX
    // OSX-specific thing here
#else
    // iOS-specific thing here
#endif
```